Effectively invalidating multiple entries from one composed key
Context

I m building a dashboard application gathering data from a Rest API
This Rest API can be requested by client applications others than the dashboard to get data
That data is then aggregated and displayed in the dashboard for analysis reasons

Scenario
A client application running in the browser is requesting an API endpoint with a dynamic param being a b64 string containing a "projectId" data in it, and some other data that are custom per user.
It means that:

multiple users requesting the API will not pass the same b64 string
all these users can call the api with the b64 string containing the same projectId
the API response might differ per user

The requested API has to do a bunch of work in the background, making computation intensive calculation. In order to speed up the response, I can cache the result on redis with a key that may look like: "{b64}:computation" => "API response"
The problem
On the dashboard, I can make a modification on the entity represented by the projectId field. When a modification happens on this specific entity, the cached entries containing the specific projectId should be invalidated and recomputed on the next call.
First thoughts
I could:

Create a set in Redis
When invalidating, requesting all the entries from the set and invalidating them one by one.

=> It seems slow
Question
How to make that effectively and working at scale when there are more than 200M (astonishing number) potential entries to invalidate?

Currently the clients refer to the entity with the 1-tuple “(projectId)”.
Define a serial number or time-based Epoch.
Now the reference becomes a “(projectId, epoch)” pair.
When a client presents an expired Epoch, send it the current one, which it will use on subsequent calls.
Use a background task to ensure the Epoch gets bumped at some minimum rate, perhaps every 10 hours.
Then you can set a redis 11-hour TTL and be confident that ancient trash won’t stick around in your keystore forever.
